# Distribution of 2-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

In the family of finite groups of order less than $2000$, there are about 99% of order $1024$, so I have a question about $2$-groups:

Let $f(n)$ be the number of non-isomorphic finite groups of order $2^{\lfloor{\rm log}_2 n\rfloor}$, $g(n)$  be the number of non-isomorphic finite groups of order less than $n+1$.

Do we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)=1$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $2^{\lfloor{\rm log}_2 n\rfloor}$ rather than $\lfloor{\rm log}_2 n\rfloor$?

Comment: I am sorry to this typo.

Comment: I think it is conjectured that the answer is yes, but the problem is open.

Comment: I haven't found such a conjecture in some book or paper.

Comment: There are some estimates about the number of non-isomorphic p-groups by G.Higman and C.C.Simons, but I don't know how to combine it with all finite groups.

Comment: Pyber, "Enumerating finite groups of given order" (Annals 1993) gives estimates that may well answer this question, but... details...

Comment: @ShiChen: In the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group#Prevalence) on $p$-groups, someone has written that it is a folklore conjecture.

Comment: @ShiChen You mean C.C. Sims, not C.C. Simons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is an empirical argument to show that the total number of (isomorphism classes of) groups of order less than $2^m$ is dwarfed by the number of order exactly $2^m$.
The number of groups of order $2^m$ is $2^{\left(\frac{2}{27}+o(1)\right)m^3}$.

Pyber, "Enumerating finite groups of given order" (Annals 1993) has shown the following. If $n=\prod_{i=i}^k p_i^{g_i}$, let $\mu(n)$ be the maximum of the $g_i$. Then the number $f(n)$ of finite groups of order $n$ satisfies $f(n)\leqslant n^{\left(\frac{2}{27}+o(1)\right)\mu^2}$ as $\mu\to\infty$. This means that the only value of $n$ less than $2^m$ with anything approaching $f(2^m)$ is $n=3.2^{m-2}$. After that come $5.2^{n-3}$ and $7.2^{m-3}$, and so on.

Consider $f(n)$ for $2^{m-1}<n<2^m$. Then for just one value of $n$, namely $n=3.2^{m-2}$, we have $\mu(n)=m-2$. For two values of $n$ we have $\mu(n)=m-3$, ..., for $2^{i-2}$ values of $n$ we have $\mu(n)=m-i$. So for $m$ large, $\sum_{2^{m-1}<n<2^m}f(n)$ is bounded by $2^{\frac{2}{27}m(m-2)^2}+2.2^{\frac{2}{27}m(m-3)^2}+4.2^{\frac{2}{27}m(m-4)^2}+\cdots$ which is much less than $f(2^m)=2^{\left(\frac{2}{27}+o(1)\right)m^3}$. Inductively, if $\sum_{n<2^{m-1}}f(n)$ is much less than $f(2^{m-1})$ then adding in this and $f(2^{m-1})$ won't change this.

There are missing details in this argument, like taking care of the $o(1)$, but I think it should be capable of being made rigorous.

**Edit**: I suppose I should have looked at the sum of $f(n)$ up to $2^{m+1}-1$, but the argument is essentially the same.

Comment: By the way, $2^{\frac{2}{27}.10^3}$ is about $2\times 10^{22}$ whereas there are only about $5 \times 10^{10}$ finite $2$-groups of order $2^{10}$. Presumably $m=10$ is too small for the generic behaviour to have set in.

Comment: Since this is a well-known open problem, I suspect the details are more challenging than you suggest, but perhaps you are right! The problem is that the results show that $ \log(f(n))/\log(g(n))$ approaches $1$ rather than $ f(n)/g(n)$.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt. Then maybe I should try to write down a rigorous argument at some point.

Comment: Here's the problem. It seems to be easy to deal with the integers $n$ with $\mu(n) \geqslant \frac{2}{3}m$, which implies that $\mu(n)$ is just the $2$-power in $n$ (this is just because $\log_3(2) < \frac{2}{3}$, which in turn is because $2^3 < 3^2$), but the problem comes with the remaining integers. We need some kind of bound on what happens when a number has a whole load of small prime factors to small powers. I'm not sure how to deal with that. It really shouldn't be a problem, but it does seem to be.